# UpgradeLoadTestResultsRepository.sql error to run a load test in VS2012 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am using VS2012 Ultimate to create Load test.after creating Web performance test and Load test projects I am unable to run web Test and also Load test for same projects.it gives the error:
The load test results database could not be opened.  Check that the load test results database specified by the connect string for your test controller (or local machine) specifies a database that contains the load test schema and that is currently available.

You can either upgrade this repository using the SQL script UpgradeLoadTestResultsRepository.sql found in the Visual Studio installation, or create a new repository from a controller using TestControllerConfigUI.exe.

I tried to Upgrade the SQL script but was unable to solve the problem.

Answer (score 8):

I solved this problem by changing the property of Load test **'Storage'** to **'None'** instead of **'Database'**

Comment: I found it, Under **Run Settings**.

Comment: this one if no database is needed,

Answer (score 2):

1.First you have to run the sql query shown in the below folder to create the database

https://i.stack.imgur.com/flTXx.png

2.By running that query the data base name LoadTest2010 will be created.

3.Now in visual studio you have to click on manage test controller and there you have to specify the server name and the database name.Then your load test will run fine.

Hope this helpful...

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this tutorial to solve the problem 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182600.aspx

running the script loadtestresultsrepository.sql stored in cd n:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE

SQL Express: SQLCMD /S localhost\sqlexpress /i loadtestresultsrepository.sql
SQL: You can install the database to any existing SQL server. For example, if you had a SQL server named ContosoServer1 you would use the following command:
SQLCMD /S ContosoServer1 -i loadtestresultsrepository.sql